# Take screen shot of Flash object with HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is an odd idea, but is it possible to take a screenshot of a flash object/video with html5? 
I am not asking how to turn a canvas element into a image since I already know that step.

Comment: I doubt this is possible.  Is there any reason you can't take this screen shot server-side?

Comment: I wouldn't be able to do a server sided screen shot

Comment: Why not?  What is the reason?

Comment: Because the screenshot needs to be live from user interaction.

Comment: You mean take a real '**Print Screen**' or take a  **frame capture**?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this directly.

Do you have access to the flash? If so you could capture the frame there and pass it back to your page through JS.

Comment: I don't have access to it directly, its not my swf file

Comment: I had a look online. Haven't tested or tried this in any manner so not sure how well / easily it will work (If at all)

Here's the idea:
1. Create your own flash object (http://devmag.org.za/2009/04/02/flash-for-free/)
2. Use flash.display.Loader to load the object (http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/load-external-swf-swf.html)
3. Grab snapshot of display object (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103374/displayobject-snapshot-in-flex-3) (This is flex, but should be similar code)
4. Adobe docs are your friend :) (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3)